# How to set StyleSheets for ComboBoxItems in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

```
<ComboBox 
        Foreground="Black"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyl}"><ComboBoxItem Content="One" IsSelected="True" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Two" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Three" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Four" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Five" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

Here I have referred to Style sheet for Every ComboBoxItem. I want to refer to stylesheets only once(with respect to ComboBoxItem).So that styles will be applied automatically when a dynamic data item is added to it.

Comment: To apply a single style to all Items you can use `ItemContainerStyle` like this `<ComboBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}">`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combobox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <!-- define data template and/or style, example: -->
         <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockItemStyle}" Text="{Binding ItemText}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Also, since you want to add/remove items dynamically, it'd be better to bind the items source to a list or collection which you can easily edit in c#. You might want to create a class like:

```
public class ComboBoxListItem
{
   public string ItemText {get; set;}
   //any other useful property
}
```

Then in your page create a `List<ComboBoxListItem> ItemList` and in the page's constructor, initialize the list with whatever data you want to. Then in your XAML DataTemplate, simply insert `"{Binding ItemText}"` wherever you want the text to appear (like I've done in the text block).

Comment: It's better to use an `ObservableCollection` for binding than a `List`. `List`s do not update the binding when changed because they do not implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but `ObservableCollection`s do.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ComboBox
        SelectedIndex="0"
        Foreground="Black"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle1}"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,280,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyl}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="One"  />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Two" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Three" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Four" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Five" />
</ComboBox>
```

Using the "ItemContainerStyle" refering to the sylesheet we created for ComboBoxItems we can easily change the Styles of ComboBoxItems whether it is declared statically or dynamically.